# Python simplejson.dumps still returns string

Tags: python, simplejson

```
Input : {"id": null, "type": null, "order_for": null, "name": "Name"}
```

code :

```
input_map = simplejson.dumps(eval(line))  
print type(input_map)
```

returns

```
<type 'str'>
```

what is wrong in here?

Thank you

Comment: Nothing, `dumps` takes some input and converts it to JSON: *"Serialize `obj` to a JSON formatted `str`."*.

Comment: I see this whrn I try to print k,v pairs => AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

```
print(input_map)
```

Also, if you use `null` in `line`, `eval` should have raised a `NameError`.
You could use `simplejson.loads` instead:

```
import simplejson
line='{"id": null, "type": null, "order_for": null, "name": "Name"}'
input_map = simplejson.loads(line)  
print(input_map)  
# {u'order_for': None, u'type': None, u'id': None, u'name': u'Name'}

print(simplejson.dumps(input_map))
# {"order_for": null, "type": null, "id": null, "name": "Name"}
```

Comment: perfect, this is where I was missing, I need json.dumps over json.loads output, thanks a lot

Comment: @daydreamer: I'm not sure if this is what you need (or maybe I misunderstood you). If you apply `dumps` on the output of `loads`, you will get the same as your original input.

Comment: @FelixKling, all I wanted a json object out of my input string, and the above mentioned way let me do it